# How transfer control between two Servlets with doPost methods?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a two servlets.

In my first servlet I use `sendRedirect` construction, but it call `doGet` from second servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    if (someCondition()) {
        resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/urlPattern");
    } else { ... }
}
```

And my second servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(req, resp);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    // something to do...
}
```

But this is not security, user may get second servlet through compose `URL`. This is not permissible for my case, I need replace call `sendRedirect` to directly use `doPost` in second servlet.

Please help me replace `resp.sendRedirect(...)` to something calling `doPost`. Thank You.

Comment: Why do you think there is security issue? If you don't want browser to show your second Servlet url you can just do forward.

Comment: @tsolakp oh! yes! this issue in my head! Thank You.